# pandas: change default date value to None

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When reading dates via `pandas.read_csv` and when a column specified in the `parse_dates` argument is not available, pandas is using the value `1900-01-01` for empty CSV cells:

```
33031   2013-01-25 16:18:59.937
33032   1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
33033   1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
33034   2013-08-06 12:45:02.560
33035   1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
33036   1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

How can I prevent pandas from doing this? I want to set the default values to `NaN` or `None` instead, but I already passed in `na_filter=False` because I don't want NaN for certain other columns.

Code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(INFOS_FILENAME, dtype={
    'authors': object,
    'created': object,
    'description': object,
    'id': object,
    'is_prerelease': bool,
    'last_updated': object,
    'listed': bool,
    'summary': object,
    'tags': object,
    'total_downloads': np.int32,
    'verified': bool,
    'version': object
}, na_filter=False,
   parse_dates=['created', 'last_updated'])
```

Comment: Can't you just filter them afterwards?

Comment: or try [pandas.DataFrame.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)?

Comment: are you sure the data is really missing?  should show up as NaT.  can't really figure this out unless you show data though.  I just tried with sample data and missing showed up as NaT for me (with parse_dates the same as you show).  also, what are the date formats in your csv?